# Auto-run script when remote git repository changes?

Tags: git, deployment, cron, githooks, crontrigger

How do I automatically run a script whenever a specified remote git repository (on bitbucket) changes?

The script will contain lines to `git pull` dependant repositories; run tests; and if tests pass, deploy then reload relevant services.

Comment: I know a variety of CI/CD software exists; but what I want is a rather simple, cut down implementation. Very simple workflow: when `foo` repository changes; run script `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use a [Bitbucket hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks) to get notified when something changes in the remote repository and probably the easiest way to implement this is to have a CI software to listen for the notification and run your `bar` script.

The complicated way is to write code yourself to receive the notification; I found [an example](http://f6design.com/journal/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/) that you might use as a starting point (and [another one](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/autodeploy-jekyll-using-bitbucket-post-commit-service-hooks-and-flask/), even more complete)

And, of course, you could always periodically poll for remote changes, but that's not very efficient. Best way is to use the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Using polling, you can check for changes on a branch from a cron job.

The `Makefile` content (supposed to be in the root folder of a git project)

```
BRANCH?=main

need_update:
    git fetch
    if [ `git rev-list HEAD...origin/${BRANCH} --count` -eq '0' ]; then \
        echo "No updates, aborting build!\n"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi

fetch:
    git pull

build:
    docker-compose build

restart:
    docker-compose down
    docker-compose up -d

upgrade: need_update fetch build restart
```

Then in your crontab add an interval and something like `su -c 'cd ~/<git-project-path> && make upgrade' <user with git credentials>`

Poorman CD is served :P